# How to Replace' \ ' with' / '

Tags: python

```
a="D:/R_SVN/hostworkspace/middleware/projects/module/com.ofss.fc.module.ac/src/com/ofss/fc/app\ac\service\writeoffrecovery\ext\WriteoffRecoveryApplicationServiceExtExecutor.java"

b=a.replace('\','/')

print b
```

Error:

```
 b=a.replace('\','/')
```

SyntaxError: `EOL while scanning string literal`

Comment: Backslash is a special character in strings. You need to escape it.

Comment: Double the first one `'\\'` to escape it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As "Backslash notation" is used for "**Escape character**", you have to add `\\`  instead of `\`

```
a.replace('\\','/')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the backslash, because it is a special character:

```
 b=a.replace('\\','/')
```

Answer (score 1):

In strings `\` is escape character e.g if there are two \ like `\\` then first one is escape character.

in `b=a.replace('\','/')` '\' is read as escape character. so you can replace it with `\\`. In this case first \ will be escaped and second one will perform operation on string `a`.

**code**:

```
>>> a="D:/R_SVN/hostworkspace/middleware/projects/module/com.ofss.fc.module.ac/src/com/ofss/fc/app\ac\service\writeoffrecovery\ext\WriteoffRecoveryApplicationServiceExtExecutor.java"
>>> b=a.replace('\\','/')
>>> print b
D:/R_SVN/hostworkspace/middleware/projects/module/com.ofss.fc.module.ac/src/com/ofss/fc/appc/service/writeoffrecovery/ext/WriteoffRecoveryApplicationServiceExtExecutor.java
```